# How to store table data in DB(PostgreSQL) in Ruby on rails when dealing with dynamic row generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails(5.0). I am trying to create an application which bills purchased items to customer.

Here i have added dynamic rows using JS and name of the element as Unique.

Now, i wanted to white list these rows and columns from UI thru params and store in DB in JSONB format.

How can i white list when i have no nested params but an array coming from UI.

Kindly help.

Comment: welcome to SO!  can you share some code to give the question a bit more context?  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `params.require(:users).permit(:name, :dynamic_item=> [])`

Answer (score 0):

you need provide more details
if I understand correctly your question
 create webservice which inserts params to DB and call it using XMLHttpRequest.
google that

```
<script>
function functname1() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.name2= function() {
   your code }    

  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "/foldername1/name?param1=value1", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

var myVar = setInterval(loadstatus, 3000);

</script>
```